# Functions in Python PCAP

Tags: python-3.x

Good day everyone 
i got a lab which ask me to write and test a function which takes one argument(a year) and returns True if the year is a leap year, or false otherwise

```
def isYearLeap(year):
    if year % 2000 == 0 or year % 2016 ==    0:
        return True
    elif year % 1900 == 0 or year % 1987 == 0:
        return False

   print(isYearLeap(2000))


testData = [1900, 2000, 2016, 1987]
testResults = [False, True, True, False]
for i in range(len(testData)):
    yr = testData[i]
    print(yr, "->", end="")
    result = isYearLeap(yr)
    if result == testResults[i]:
        print("Ok")
     else:
        print("Failed")
```

i actually dont know if my function and the function body is correct though the lab prepared the testing code

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea to hardcode test values inside your function. Leap year should be calculcated in following way:

> Leap Years are any year that can be exactly divided by 4 (such as 2016, 2020, 2024, etc)
>
> except if it can be exactly divided by 100, then it isn't (such as 2100, 2200, etc)
>
> except if it can be exactly divided by 400, then it is (such as 2000, 2400)

So final code will look like this: (I added more test cases)

```
def isYearLeap(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)


testData = [1900, 2000, 2016, 1987, 2100, 2400, 2019]
testResults = [False, True, True, False, False, True, False]
for i in range(len(testData)):
    yr = testData[i]
    print(yr, "->", end=" ")
    result = isYearLeap(yr)
    if result == testResults[i]:
        print("Ok")
    else:
        print("Failed")
```